# How to make django templates unicode enabled?

Tags: django, templates, unicode

I need help making django templates work with unicode.
I am using Django 1.8 with python 2.7 on CENTOS 6.5.  MySQL database is created with utf-8. When django render some templates, I got error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 13: ordinal not in  range(128)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://bluenanta.com:8000/
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError
Exception Value:    
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
Exception Location: /home/bluenant/python/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/utils/encoding.py in force_text, line 94
Python Executable:  /home/bluenant/python/bin/python
```

=====================================

Following example of code containing variables that may contain non ascii strings (e.g. image.species}} or {{image.foto}}

```
{% for image in random_list%}
   <li>{% if image.source_url %}
        <a href="{{image.source_url}}" target="_blank">{% endif %}
    <img src="{{ image.image_url }}" width="150"/>
    <br><font size=1px>{{image.id}} {{image.species}} {{image.variance}} 
    {%   if image.form %} forma {{image.form}}{% endif %}<br>
    {% if image.foto %} photo: {{image.foto}}{% endif %}
    {% if image.source_url %}</a>{% endif %}</font>
   </li>
{% endfor %}
```